# Rails erb template list all functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, erb

Within a Rails html.erb template I can view all of the available instance variables using:

```
<%= instance_variables %>
```

Is there an equivalent feature for listing all of the helper methods available to be called from within this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly same as instance variables

```
<%= methods %>
```

in  your rails html.erb file

Comment: Thanks, I had already attempted `functions`, `helper_methods`, `instance_methods`, `ApplicationHelper` etc but somehow `methods` evaded my list. Hopefully this will be of use to others too.